# WPF unable to choose right DLL if several versions are loaded within same AppDomain

Tags: wpf, xaml, plugins, dll, appdomain

We are developing plugins to be added to a giant & awesome software. We often reuse the same WPF controls so we packaged them and created separate assemblies for each of them.

Sometimes, we need to load 2 different plugins within the same instance of the software. At that point, if the 2 plugins use the same reusable control but with different DLL versions, WPF doesn't seem to be able to choose the correct one. Both DLLs are correctly loaded (seen using Process Explorer).

What we already tried :

- Binding redirects
- Assembly redirects
- Overridden assembly resolving

Is there any solution to indicate to WPF which version of the same DLL it needs to select for requested namespace in XAML ? Could we force the use of the latest in some way (this would work for us) ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at my commit o SharpDevelop: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/commit/b3ea4a0efb7e3b8e083f8be40ea6f7e03ff44604

I fixed this, by using a custom "InitializComponent" Call! ("SpecialInitializeComponent") and using special merged ResourceDictionarys: VersionedAssemblyResourceDictionary! Hope that helps you!

Comment: I'll test that in the next month and come back with the result ASAP.